# How to change charset response header and response encoding for C# .net core web api json response?

Tags: c#, encoding, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have simple .net core wep api application with contoller method like that

```
   [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult  Get(int id)
    {
        var myObj= _testRepository.TryGetById(id);
        if (myObj== null)
        {
            return new NotFoundResult();
        }
        return new JsonResult(myObj);

    }
```

This method return json response with headers

```
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date    Sat, 26 Aug 2017 12:01:00 GMT
Server  Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
```

I need to change **charset=utf-8** header to **charset=utf-16**. How can i do that?

**UPDATE**

I wanted to change **charset** header, because i needed to get string fields inside json response escaped like that

```
{ "city": "\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0431\u0438\u0440\u0441\u043a"}
```

This problem can be solved by changing code inside `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddMvc();
    ...
}
```

=>

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.StringEscapeHandling =  StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii;
        });
    ...
}
```

But I'm really confused, I have not found on the web any info about how to change default **charset** header. I think it must be trivial operation for any api framework.

Comment: Why do you need to change it to utf-16 charset?

Comment: i need to return uncode strings inside fields of response json object

Comment: UTF-8 supports unicode. What about it isn't working for you?

Comment: I think i not fully understand how it works, but for external test cases i need to return reponse likei this { "city": "\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0431\u0438\u0440\u0441\u043a"}.So I think utf-16 instead of utf-8 will do this

Comment: @Frank59 Json parsers can handle this. See for ex,  `var jstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { city= "Росбирск" }, new JsonSerializerSettings() {  StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii});` Output: `{"city":"\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0431\u0438\u0440\u0441\u043a"}`

Comment: @L.B, thanks a lot! It's works and now my string fields inside json response are escaped. You can post your comment as asnwer and i will like this. But i am really confused, that i not found in msdn and internet any info about how to change default charset header. As for me it must be trivial operation for each api framework.

Comment: @Frank59 I am not familiar with asp.net but here is how you can do it in WCF. `return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(jsonstring, "application/json", Encoding.Unicode);` in Asp.net There may be a way while constructing *ActionResult*

Comment: May be using of ActionResult is valid way, but interesting to change default charset for all responses in global mvc settings. But it's a teoretical interest. My concrete problem was solved. Thanks!

Comment: I do not think there is an option. Json encoding beyond utf8 is rare. And JsonResult is opinionated. You could write a custom Action Result, serializing the structure to a .NET string and then return a byte array with your preferred encoding. I would also recommend to open a ticket at https://GitHub.com/aspnet/Mvc . Make them aware of your needs. They are very friendly.

Comment: So I opened sources and found that default encoding and default header cased by default constructor of JsonResultExecutor class. Will try to find way to owerwrite that.